# How to manipulate a set of images collectively along the screen in Three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl

I have been trying to recreate https://anatoletouvron.fr/ portfolio and cannot recreate the convex and concave type of distortion of the images when we scroll fast on the site. Does anyone have any pointers? I tried applying all the shaders I extracted from the site.

I got the post-processing part to work but not the images. When I apply shaders to them all images get manipulated at the same time and not in relation to their position on the screen. How do I go about achieving this? The site seems to be built in OGL. I am trying to recreate the same in Three.js. Any sort of pointers can help, Three.js noob here.

Comment: You are a noob? To recreate the OGL zoetrope in three.js, create a cylinder. Post-processing works on geometry as well as shaders. Such is my friendly response in direct answer to your question. Should you choose to continue this route, use the radian to orient the portal.